# how to draw graph of X / ln(x)

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, graphing-functions

My question is to draw the graph of x/ln(x) ;where ln represents natural log.
I know that the graph will decline from x= 0 to 1 and at 1 there will be an asymptote but I don't know  what will the graph when x>1
pls solve using application of derivatives

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the derivative of $x/\log_e(x)$? When is it positive, zero or negative? What would that tell you?